# Pass values to controller action onclick and navigate to page ASP.Net Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have an `<a></a>` that I am using to call an action in a controller to navigate to a report page. The action looks like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string year, string month, string groupId, string forback)
{
    // Do stuff with passed data           

    return View();
}
```

Normally I would use the `<a></a>` tag with a controller, action and route values, for example:

`<a id="showReport" asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-action="Index" asp-route-groupId="123" ...>Show Report</a>`

The issue I am having is that the `groupId` needs to be taken from a select when the user clicks the `<a></a>`. As an example this is what I am using at the moment:

```
$('#showReport').click(function () {
    $.get("/ControllerName/Index", { year: @DateTime.Now.Year, month: @DateTime.Now.Month, groupId: $('#groupSelect').val(), forback: "for" } );
});
```

This returns the HTML of the page but does not navigate to it.

From further reading I should not be using ajax to simply reload the entire HTML of the page, so how can I navigate to a controller action, pass in the values required on click and then load the returned page?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JSON with the URL and change the window.location using JavaScript at client side:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string year, string month, string groupId, string forback)
{
    // Do stuff with passed data           

    return Json(new { result = "Redirect", url = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") });
}
```

In client side , redirect to expected url by using `window.location`:

```
 $('#showReport').click(function () {
    $.get("/ControllerName/Index", { year: @DateTime.Now.Year, month: @DateTime.Now.Month, groupId: $('#groupSelect').val(), forback: "for" }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.result == 'Redirect') {
            //redirecting to page 
            window.location = data.url;
        }
    });
});
```